# useState hook's set State function not working properly with socket.io

Tags: javascript, reactjs, socket.io, frontend, react-hooks

I have a component that uses react hooks and socketio:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import io from "socket.io-client";

const Live = () => {
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
  const ENDPOINT = "localhost:5000";

  useEffect(() => {
    socket = io(ENDPOINT);
    socket.on("message", (message) => {
      setMessages((messages) => [message, ...messages]);
      //setMessages([message, ...messages]); //It doesn't work
    });
  }, [ENDPOINT]);

  // rest of the code

};
```

If I use the `setMessages([message, ...messages])`, it doesn't work and upon receiving a new message from socket, all the previous message in `messages` array are gone. What is the reason behind this behavior?

Comment: `messages` goes stale in the commented out update. Using the updater function ensures you have the most recent copy of state.

Comment: Socket.io is async, as such if you don't use the function form, messages will be a closure on what messages was when the function was first invoked.

Comment: So, particularly in which scenario should I use it with extra function?

Comment: You pass a function to socket.on and in that function `messages` is available as a closure. But when component re renders the effect is not re run so the messages is a [stale closure](https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-hooks-stale-closures/). When you pass a function to a state setter then that function is called by React with the current state value, that's why `setMessages((messages) => [message, ...messages]);` works.

Comment: Your effect should return a function that disconnects when component is unmounted or effect is re run.

Answer (score 2):

I don't recommend `useState` here to do what you're doing. Instead, consider `useReducer`

```js
const Live = () => {
  const ENDPOINT = "localhost:5000";

  const [{ messages }, dispatch] = useReducer((state, action) => {
    if (action.type === 'NEW_MESSAGE') {
      state.messages.push(action.message)
      return state
    }
    return state
  }, { messages: [] })

  useEffect(() => {
    socket = io(ENDPOINT);
    socket.on("message", (message) => {
      dispatch({ type: 'NEW_MESSAGE', message })
    });
  }, [ENDPOINT])

  // rest of the code
};
```

from the React docs on `useReducer`

> useReducer is usually preferable to useState when you have complex state logic that involves multiple sub-values or when the next state depends on the previous one.

In your case, the next `messages` state depends on the previous `messages` state.